# Ошибка в WPF Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-toolkit

Вылетает такая ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Не удается изменить логический дочерний узел
>   данного узла, так как в это время выполняется переход по дереву.

View:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="bubbles" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240.763,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="311.273" Width="355.778" Title="График">
    <chartingToolkit:BubbleSeries IndependentValuePath="Key" DependentValuePath="Value" IsSelectionEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></chartingToolkit:BubbleSeries>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

View back side:

```
//построение графика по нажатию на кнопку
private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>(); 
    if (RadioButtonX.IsChecked == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
            if (points[i].X == Convert.ToDouble(txtNum.Text))
                 valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(points[i].Y), Convert.ToInt32(points[i].Z)));
    }
    if (RadioButtonY.IsChecked == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
            if (points[i].Y == Convert.ToInt64(txtNum.Text))
                valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(points[i].X), Convert.ToInt32(points[i].Z)));
    }
    if (RadioButtonZ.IsChecked == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
            if (points[i].Z == Convert.ToInt64(txtNum.Text))
                valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(points[i].X), Convert.ToInt32(points[i].Y)));
    }
    //Setting data for bubble chart
    bubbles.DataContext = valueList;
}
```

Comment: в какой строчке падает исключение?

Comment: bubbles.DataContext = valueList;

Comment: грязный код....Если уж используете именование контролов, то стоит придерживаться стиля и дальше, т.е. заносить данные сразу в коллекцию BubbleSeries

Comment: я уже на это исправили кстати, весьма странный метод.

Comment: исключение все равно падает или нет?

Comment: нет его больше нету, когда заново проект создал и подключил всё

Comment: у меня другой вопрос: как dynamic data display построить bubble chart я нигде не могу найти примеров про bubble chart а на любые отступы от того что есть ругается библиотека

Comment: `dynamic data display` немного устарела, вам обязательно её использовать?

Comment: там просто всё из коробки есть: в плане зум и цвет точек можно свой задавать, а мне это важно

Comment: такое должно быть в любом библиотеке, советую использовать OxyPlot или LiveCharts. Оформите отдельный вопрос, попробую написать ответ. (Можно даже два вопроса с метками по каждой из этих библиотек :))

Comment: Главное уточните какой тип графика вы хотите получить

Comment: вот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661146/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B2-wpf