# Сложный график из точек в WPF

Tags: wpf

Мне нужно создать график из большого кол-ва точек. Цвет каждой точки задан.
График построенный в live-charts: [image: график live-charts]

Но как видно что все точки синие, а мне нужно для каждой свой цвет, а также добавить zoom для графика.

Код XAML:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Click="UpdateAllOnClick" Margin="393,85,700,731">
            Move All
</Button>
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" Margin="99,218,50,140"/>
```

Код WPF (код очень грубый, но это хотябы нарисовать что нибудь для примера):

```
    private void UpdateAllOnClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChartValues<ScatterPoint> ValuesMy = new ChartValues<ScatterPoint>();
        ScatterSeries scatSer = new ScatterSeries();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
            if (points[i].X == 1)
                ValuesMy.Add(new ScatterPoint(points[i].Y, points[i].Z));


        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new ScatterSeries
            {
                Values = ValuesMy,
                MinPointShapeDiameter = 10,
                MaxPointShapeDiameter = 10
            }
        };

        DataContext = this;

    }
```

points - массив с точками.

Comment: ещё хорошо бы добавить подписи осей

Comment: Вариант с группировкой данных по цвету точки и отображение в виде нескольких серий не рассматриваете?

Comment: а можете подробнее про это написать, мои навыки владения live-charts малы

Comment: ну к слову у меня жёсткая привязка цвета к точкам

Comment: например, у вас есть тип точек - `type MyPoint = {X:float; Y:float; Property:PropertyType}` и некоторый их набор, который нужно отобразить на графике. Возможности LiveCharts позволяют задавать тип для всех точек серии. Поэтому вместо того, чтобы заносить всю коллекцию в одну серию мы можем сгруппировать набор по нашему свойству Property и каждый новый набор отобразить в своей серии

Comment: прошу прощения, но в scatterPoint, который является единственным форматом моего типа точек, третий и единственный дополнительный параметр weight или вы предлагаете по нему и искать нужную коллекцию точек

Comment: Нет, предлагаю не это. Давайте вы просто сформулируете вашу задачу более подробно, чтобы была возможность написать пример

Comment: нужно разместить точки на графике с определённым цветом. Координаты и цвет имеются

Comment: случайно не задачу кластеризации решаете?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58082/discussion-between-ev-hyper-and-firelion).